# How to access child class properties from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have the following structure of classes:

```
class A
{
    IEnumerable<int> a;
}

class B:A
{
    IEnumerable<int> b;
}

class C:B
{
    IEnumerable<int> c;
}

class D:C
{
    IEnumerable<int> d;
}

class E
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

Now I want to access all the fields a,b,c,d from the created object a.
Is it possible to do so and how?

Also there could be a scenario where this inheritance tree might grow. So how should i take care of this, i.e., a is able to access the fields of new classes without any code changes in the future.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You're thinking backwards, I think.

Comment: It is not possible, because A do not have those fields

Comment: Why `A a = new A();` and not `D d = new D();` ?

Comment: Class A has one property `a`. It won't have properties `b`,`c`,`d`. I don't understand your question. I don't think you understand your problem space.

Comment: @Saurabh if you need to access a property from the base class, you are doing something wrong. Keep that in mind for your future designs

Comment: This would be a violation of the object orientated pattern. see the Liskov substitution principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for a deeper discussion. As Jon said, the language doesn't feature this and any solution that uses reflection has a  smell

Comment: @Jon: it'#s not even possible with reflection: the OP has created an instance of `A`.  There is no field `b`, `c` or `d` on that instance, reflection or no!

Comment: @DanPuzey: You are so right :-)

Comment: I think you don't understand OO principles correctly; so read some books to learn about them first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access fields `b`, `c`, or `d` because they don't exist on an instance of `A`.

If you want to create a class with all of those fields, you have one: `D`.  Create an instance of `D` instead.

**EDIT:** some possible thoughts on what you might be meaning instead:

1. you may mean that you want to create `A a = new D()` and then access the properties of the child type `D` from your `main()`.  This is possible with casting, but it's easier if you just declare the variable as a `D` in the first place.
2. you may mean that you want the code of your class `A` to be able to reference properties in class `D`.  This is directly possible with reflection or casting, but this would not be recommended as the design would be very fragile and hard to read.  The better solution is to user *overriding*, where a method in class `A` (that doesn't use properties in `D`) can be overridden in class `D` to have more specific functionality.
3. you may mean that you want your `new A()` to have all of the properties `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.  In this case, you have your basic understanding wrong: inheritance works the other way around.  Class `D` has all four properties, not class `A`.

**FURTHER EDIT:**

Re-reading your code, you also have a further problem: all of your fields are implicitly `private` (as this is the default).  Therefore, none of your fields will be accessible to other classes in the inheritance chain.  You need to mark them as `protected` or `public` instead for them to be visible.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This was asked in one of the job interviews. Just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: @Saurabh If this was asked in a job interview then either you didn't get the problem quite right, or you don't want to work there because their interviewer doesn't have even a basic understanding of programming.

Answer (score 1):

An instance of A only has the property a.  You could define a variable  of type A and assign it an instance of type B but you wouldn't be able to access the property b from it.

`A a = new A();  //a.a is available

A b = new B(); //only .a is available, but the assignment  works because of inheritance`

Comment: Worth noting that you could use `((B)b).b` to access the property in your second case.

Answer (score 1):

```
D d = new D();
```

now you have access to 
    a, b, c, d;
object a does not contain definition for 
    IEnumerable b, or c or d,
only object of type D contains definition for all Instances of IEnumerables

Answer (score 1):

If your base class is aware of the variables in the child class and wants to access them, they should be defined in the base class itself (and then inherited by the child classes).